# Sharepoint API filter result

Tags: list, sharepoint-rest-api, filter, list-view-threshold

When using following request:

```
[...]/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('SVC')/items?$select=FileRef,File_x0020_Type&$top=5000
```

I get the top 5000 items in the result. However when adding following filter I get an error:

```
[...]/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('SVC')/items?$select=FileRef,File_x0020_Type&$top=5000&$filter=(File_x0020_Type eq 'docx')
```

The error message is:

```
2147024860, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException

The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.
```

Why do I get the error message? The list threshold is 5000 and the top 5000 limitation is still included in the request.

Comment: Is it working if you try `$top=100` or `$top=500` with filter condition?

Comment: It is also not working when I use $top=1

Comment: How many files do you have in your document library? Do you have indexing on  `File Type` in your document library?

Comment: there are currently 5389 files in library with no special adjustments, just a default document library.

Comment: Try adding an `orderby` clause on an index column